# Poetry: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python'

Tags: python, python-poetry

OSX 14.2.1 on M1, Python 3.11.4, Poetry 1.7.1
I set config virtualenvs.in-project = true

If I run "poetry install" or "poetry env info"
I get the error:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python'

If I run a "poetry check"
I get:

> All set!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

got the same problem (also OX). For me this helped before running `poetry install`.

```
rm -rf .venv && poetry env remove --all
poetry cache clear --all .
```